# Select with attribute not in model without attr_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to attach some data to my form not directly linked to my model.

I can do it with a `radio_button` but not at all with a `select` (`collection_select` etc).

Here is my code:

```
= form_for @user, url: user_path(@user) do |f| 
  // This is working
  = f.radio_button :my_field_not_in_model, true, checked: true
    | Yes
  = f.radio_button : my_field_not_in_model, false, checked: false
    | No
  br
  // This is not working
  = f.label 'Another user'
  = f.collection_select :reference_user_id, @user.group.users, :id, :email
```

Basically, I would like to attach a reference user to make a special analysis on my controller before removing this attribute before the final update. I don't want to create an `attr_accessor` on my model each time I need more data for a special treatment on my controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem arises from the fact that you use the `form_for` form builder to generate your selection values. If you inspect the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) you'll see that `collecion_select` expects an object, and will return the values from a specified *method* called on said object for its values.

What you need is a regular select tag

```
select_tag "reference_user_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@users.group.users, :id, :email)
```

This should yield the correct HTML for your purposes.

See the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag) for more information on the usage of `select_tag`, or [these docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select) for more information on the `options_from_collection_for_select`.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I expected !